# Dealing cards and returning leftovers

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to make an card deal program.

- There are 5 players.
- The deck order is given.
- The program deals the cards one at a time from the top of the deck.

  - The top of the desk is the start of the stack.
- The program returns:

  - the 5 player hands and
  - the cards still in the pack.

Function:

```
def deal_cards(FIVE,card_list):
    card_list = = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] * 4
    hand_one = []
    hand_two = []
    hand_three = []
    hand_four = []
    hand_five = []
    for i in card_list:
        hand_one = card_list.append(i)
        hand_two = card_list.pop(i + 1)
        hand_three = card_list.pop(i + 2)
        hand_four = card_list.pop(i + 3)
        hand_five = card_list.pop(i + 4)

    return hand_one, hand_two, hand_three, hand_four, hand_five
```

Main:

```
print("Deck - ", end="")
print(*card_list)
hand_one, hand_two, hand_three, hand_four, hand_five = deal_cards(card_list)
print("Player 1 - ", end="")
print(*hand_one)
print("Player 2 - ", end="")
print(*hand_two)
print("Player 3 - ", end="")
print(*hand_three)
print("Player 4 - ", end="")
print(*hand_four)
print("Player 5 - ", end="")
print(*hand_five)
```

Comment: Ok, so what's your question?

Comment: I don't know what to do from here and can't get the code working. The same goes for returning the leftover values. I'm questioning mainly about the way I did to put the cards in the players hand to see if its optimal or not. I get blanks printing this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Your given code doesn't compile, let alone run.  You haven't specified the problem.  "I don't know what to do from here and can't get the code working" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use this :

```
colors=[('spades','♠'), ('hearts','♥'),('diamonds','♦'),('clubs','♣')]
colors=[s for (n,s) in colors]
faces=['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','1','J','Q','K']

cards=list(__import__("itertools").product(colors, faces))

__import__("random").shuffle(cards)

nbplayers=5
nbcards=6

def cardstostr(cards):
    return ",".join(map(lambda (c,f): f+c, cards))

for i in range(nbplayers):
    print cardstostr(cards[nbcards*i:nbcards*(i+1)])
print cardstostr(cards[nbplayers*nbcards:])
```